# Combining two string with dot (.) in Perl

Tags: string, perl

I've got a problem in my Perl program when I try to combine a computer name in a string with a string with dot (.), please see the code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

chomp(my $COMPUTERNAME = `hostname`); #this should give the computername e.g CH-B7G33
my $complog = $COMPUTERNAME.".log"; 
print "$complog";
```

The expected output would be.

```
CH-B7G33.log
```

But what I got is wrong, it printed out.

```
.logB7G33
```

Did I do something wrong in the code? Please help me, I'm a Perl beginner and by the way sorry to my English.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The return value from your system call contains a `\r` at the end, which `chomp` is not clearing away.  So your string ends up looking like `CH-B7G33\r.log` which when printed causes the terminal to display `CH-B7G33` then move the cursor back to the start of the line, and then display `.log` which overwrites the characters, leading to the incorrect output you saw.

Using a substitution works well, and will handle both `\r` and `\n` line endings (and other trailing space, as written here).

```
(my $COMPUTER_NAME = `hostname`) =~ s/\s+$//;
```

Answer (score 9):

```
use Sys::Hostname;
print hostname . ".log";
```

There's no need to `chomp` or break out to a shell when there's a nice library function that does what you want.

Comment: I've already tried this one but in the other machine where Perl is running in cygwin. I can't make this run which I think I still need to install the module.

Comment: No need to install, it's part of the Perl core distro. `$ corelist Sys::Hostname␤Sys::Hostname was first released with perl 5`

Comment: @quinekxi, What symptom are you seeing on cygwin?  Do you have an error message, or does it produce confusing or incorrect output?  If so, what?  Does `perl -c` produce any error trace under cygwin?

Comment: Mike Samuel, I have an error msg, it says: "Can't locate Sys/Hostname.pm in @INC blah blah"